# is Calling new Runnable, or Calling new Class Safe For Memory Management?

Tags: android

hello guys hope you having a nice day, i have and interface that works in background , on one of its methods , it reads a line of string and calls a method of implemented class, like this :

```
     while ( (receivedString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null &&  
                       activity != null) {
                    activity.OnFileRowRead(receivedString, stmt, count);
                    count++;

                  }
```

and it is called for like 1million times,the method currently returns a boolean, so it be thread safe, but it is obviously slower this way. the method is this :

```
 if(row != null && row.contains("/.~n/")){
                String [] splitted = row.split("\\/.~n/");

                for (String str : splitted){
                    String[] spl = str.split("\\/.nn/");

                    if(spl.length == 8){

                          int version = Integer.valueOf(NotNull(spl[7]));
                          stmt.bindLong(1, Integer.valueOf(NotNull(spl[0])));
                          stmt.bindLong(2, version);
                          stmt.bindString(3, NotNull(spl[3]));
                          stmt.bindDouble(4, Double.valueOf(NotNull(spl[1])));
                          stmt.bindDouble(5, Double.valueOf(NotNull(spl[2])));
                          stmt.bindString(6, NotNull(spl[4]));
                          stmt.bindString(7, NotNull(spl[5]));
                          stmt.bindString(8, NotNull(spl[6]));
                          stmt.bindString(9, version == 0 ? MapActivity_Database.STATUS_UNAVAILABLE : MapActivity_Database.STATUS_AVAILABLE);
                          stmt.execute();

                          str = null;

                          stmt.clearBindings();

                        count ++;
                    }
                   }
                  splitted = null;
                  }

            return true;
        }
```

now i am thinking that method on the class that implemented this, creates a new class and returns the boolean value or runs a new runnable , and returns value , the method is fast as you can see , but 1million is too much yet, is it safe for the memory and thread to do so? i mean will gc be able to recycle these ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to run the method 1million times sequential or synchronous? If its synchronous the memory needed is ofc 1million times higher. But after the threads ends the memory should be freed as far as I can say from your snippets (otherwise you have to free them manually on threads end). So I think its "memory safe".

If its thread safe its hard to say with that less information - are there any objects/resources which are used from multiple threads? Are these objets thread safe? If not you have to have to implement if manually (catchword: mutex).

Last but not least: are you sure this is the only way to solve your problem? Calling one method a million times seems like bad practice - may there are some callbacks you could use?

Comment: like i said, they are called when a file's row is readed, from a single thread, the method must be either instantiated or be synchronous , and since it is too fast, memory wont suffer that much from creating, im thinking about gc,  plus call back is same as instantiating, which i was asking

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you mean by 'instantiated'. But the GC doesnt care if he has to clean a threads garbage or a functions